# Implicit declaration of function fseeko

Tags: c, large-files, fseek

I'm trying to use the `fseeko` function in combination with the GCC-compiler in order to work with files that are larger than 4GiB in C. Now, everything works and I am able to work with files of over 4GiB, but GCC keeps complaining that the `fseeko` function is implicitly declared. This is a minimal working example of the the source code that generates this message:

```
#define __USE_LARGEFILE64
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE

#include "MemoryAllocator.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

typedef struct BlockReader {
    char* fileName;
    // Total filesize of the file with name fileName in bytes.
    unsigned long long fileSize;
    // Size of one block in bytes.
    unsigned int blockSize;
    // Defines which block was last read.
    unsigned int block;
    // Defines the total amount of blocks
    unsigned int blocks;
} BlockReader;

unsigned char* blockreader_read_raw_block(BlockReader* reader, long startPos, unsigned int length, size_t* readLength) {
    FILE* file = fopen(reader->fileName, "rb");

    unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*) mem_alloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (length + 1));

    FSEEK(file, startPos, 0);
    fclose(file);

    // Terminate buffer
    buffer[length] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

I cannot find anywhere what header I have to include to fix this warning. The exact warning that GCC gives is this:

```
src/BlockReader.c: In function ‘blockreader_read_block’:
src/BlockReader.c:80:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fseeko’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  FSEEK(file, reader->blockSize * reader->block, 0);
```

Comment: `fseeko` is in Posix,  not standard C

Comment: Assuming that `MemoryAllocator.h` defines mem_alloc(x) as malloc(x), and FSEEK as fseeko, then this program compiles fine on a POSIX platform. However, if you are trying to build on Windows, it will not work.

Comment: What exactly is the compiler command line you are using?  Have you set `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to an appropriate value before including any headers?

Comment: `__USE_LARGEFILE64`, `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`, and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` are all incorrect. Read the documentation rather than cargo-culting random stuff. `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` is what you're looking for, but it's independent of the reason why `fseeko` is not visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using one of the `-std` options like `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`, these request a fully conforming standard C environment where POSIX interfaces are not exposed by default (exposing them would be non-conforming because they're in the namespace reserved for the application). You need to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to an appropriate value to get them. `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` on the command line, or

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

in your source file before including any headers, would be the way to do this.

Also, while this is not your immediate problem, note that `__USE_LARGEFILE64`, `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`, and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` are all incorrect. The only thing you need to do to get 64-bit `off_t` is `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` on the command line or `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` in your source file before including any headers.